# "dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege". Cannot remove all configuration info from removed packages, sudo doesn't work

Tags: uninstall, sudo, dpkg

I want to run this command (see section `4` from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Removal_commands):

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge
```

I use `sudo` at the beginning but anyway I get an error:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge
[sudo] password for user:
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

Why `sudo` doesn't work? What else should I type?

Answer (score 8):

`sudo` only applies to a single command, not the whole pipeline. In your case, the command ran as superuser was `dpkg -l` – which is not necessary.

On the contrary, the command really requiring the superuser access in your pipeline is `dpkg --purge`, so prepend `sudo` directly to it.

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

By the way, `awk` can [filter rows using regular expressions](https://www.tecmint.com/use-linux-awk-command-to-filter-text-string-in-files/) just like `grep` does, so you can save one command:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

Answer (score 6):

try to login as root, to gain the super-power, you can do this by typing:

```
sudo -i
```

then write (*copy/paste :: Ctrl + C / Ctrl + Shift + V <-- paste in terminal*) your command in terminal, and it should work

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -i dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge
```

This may run your command with **ROOT** priviliges.
Sudo and root is different. [Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Comment: This neither explains why it isn't working, nor what to do instead. See @Melebius answer for both.